# How can I use || between values to disable a button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
 yy {{ utilityService.isNotNumber(option.selectedSubject) }} yy
 zz {{ !grid.pristine }} zz
 aa {{ fetching != 0 }} aa
 <button class="small"
    data-ng-disabled="utilityService.isNotNumber(option.selectedSubject) ||
                      !grid.pristine || grid.fetching"
```

When this outputs this is what I get:

```
yy false yy zz false zz aa true aa
```

and a button that's not disabled.

Can someone give me some advice. I do not understand why the button doesn't get disabled as one of the three conditions is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetching != 0` is `true`

What you are actually ORing is `grid.fetching`.

Try using

```
data-ng-disabled="utilityService.isNotNumber(option.selectedSubject) ||
                  !grid.pristine || fetching != 0"
```